# help installing this Ruby app from github

Tags: ruby-on-rails

http://github.com/bestbuyremix/BBYIDX

I manually installed all the gem's required that where in the .gem file, for some reason bundle install didn't work (guess b/c no GEMFILE ?)

I am using rvm, so I have rails 2.1.1 running also.

when I go into the main folder for the application, and run:

```
rake db:migrate --trace
```

I get this error:

```
rake db:migrate --trace
(in /Users/sdd/dev/sources/BBYIDX)
rake aborted!
undefined method `new!' for Rational:Class
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/vendor/tzinfo-0.3.9/tzinfo/offset_rationals.rb:30:in `<module:OffsetRationals>'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/vendor/tzinfo-0.3.9/tzinfo/offset_rationals.rb:28:in `<module:TZInfo>'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/vendor/tzinfo-0.3.9/tzinfo/offset_rationals.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `block in require'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:355:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `require'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/vendor/tzinfo-0.3.9/tzinfo/time_or_datetime.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `block in require'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:355:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `require'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/vendor/tzinfo-0.3.9/tzinfo/timezone.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `block in require'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:355:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `require'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/vendor/tzinfo-0.3.9/tzinfo.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `block in require'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:355:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `require'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `block in require'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:355:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `require'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/activesupport-2.1.1/lib/active_support.rb:57:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/rails-2.1.1/lib/tasks/misc.rake:12:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/rails-2.1.1/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `load'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/rails-2.1.1/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/rails-2.1.1/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `each'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@rails211/gems/rails-2.1.1/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/Users/sdd/dev/sources/BBYIDX/Rakefile:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `block in run'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/sdd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails 2.1.1 is very old and will not work with ruby 1.9. Ruby 1.8 had Rational.new! but 1.9 does not.

http://fossplanet.com/f14/%5Bruby-core-23843%5D-differences-rational-between-1-8-1-9-a-32052/

Answer (score 0):

As far as issues with bundler, for a clean version of ruby (and rubygems), you'll need to `gem install bundler` in order to be able to `bundle install`